# Add fixed item to select2

Tags: jquery-select2, select2-rails

I am using select2 gem in rails

gem version: 3.5.9.3
select2 version: 3.5.2

Haml view:

```
= form_tag('cards/search/', method: :get, remote: true, class: 'navbar-form navbar-right') do
  .form-group
    = hidden_field_tag :q, '', id: 'search', class: 'form-control',
      style: 'width: 250px;',
      data: { 'ajax-url' => search_path, placeholder: 'placeholder' }
```

In coffescript file

```
$ ->
  $('#search').select2
    minimumInputLength: 1
    ajax:
      dataType: 'json'
      delay: 250
      data: (params) ->
        q: params
      results: (data) ->
        results: data.q
```

[image: Result]

How can I add fixed item to the bottom of options? No matter what I typed in search form.

I tried:

```
$('#search').append{id: 'test', text: 'test'}
```

But didn't saw that option.

Comment: May be here https://select2.org/data-sources/arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two solutions I came up with are:

1. Create a decorator for `select2`.
   Which IMO is quite a cumbersome task since there isn't really any documentation on how to do it that I've found.
   The best resource I found that helped me was Kvein Brown's reply on this thread:

   > https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/select2/s4hAHyBrYqc
2. The other way to do it, and probably the easiest if you're just using one `select2` on the page is to listen for `select2`'s open event and then just use `jQuery` to append a element where you want it.